# WebView android (open browser)

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I need to open webbview currunt URL in Browser when button is clicked.

Now have this code:

```
 WebView webview;
private WebView mWebView;
/**
  * Dichiariamo l'attributo di classe url in cui  
  * salviamo l'indirizzo web che aprir¬à la webview
  */
private String url = "http://www.google.com";
```

Have need code for open current url webview in browser.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to load url in webview or in browser?

Answer (score 2):

You can create `mWebView` instance field of type `WebView` and then assign it to your webview id from `xml` like this,

```
WebView mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```

and then load the url using `loadUrl` method,

```
        webView.loadUrl("your URL here");
```

If you want to load this url in browser when button is clicked,

```
        Button button1;
        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("your URL"));
                startActivity(browserIntent);

            }
        });
```

Comment: I have need current url

Comment: what do you mean current url ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String url = "http://www.google.com";
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I have need click in button1